# How to persist class that depends on internal list using Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, list, persistence

I have class `History` that stores, well, a history of `State` objects. For that purpose, `History` maintains an internal list, more precisely an `ArrayList`:

```
// states is 'life cycle object' -> cascading
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private final List<State> states;

History() {
    states = new ArrayList<State>();
}
```

Method `equals` relies on field `states`:

```
public final boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof History)) {
        return false;
    }
    History other = (History) obj;
    // we do not use fields to ensure compatibility with lazy loading
    if (!Objects.equal(getStates(), other.getStates())) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In the unit tests of my model, method `equals` behaves like expected; it is tested by [equalsverifier](http://code.google.com/p/equalsverifier/).

However, above the persistence layer, method `equals` behaves differently. Although two `History` instances have the same list of states, they are not equal.

This is due to Hibernate's class `PersistentBag` which - deliberately - violates the collection API:

```
/**
 * Bag does not respect the collection API and do an
 * JVM instance comparison to do the equals.
 * The semantic is broken not to have to initialize a
 * collection for a simple equals() operation.
 * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
 */
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return super.equals(obj);
}
```

Well, this renders my `equals` method useless...

How could I persist class `History` **without** loosing semantics of `equals`?

P.S.: There is an corresponding open issue at https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5409.

**Update**

This basically is my test case:

1. I create history `h` and add some states.
2. In session `s1`, I save `h` to the database using Hibernate.
3. In session `s2`, I fetch `h` from the database using some search query again via Hibernate. Let's call that fetched instance `h*`.
4. Now, I call `h.equals(h*)`. I would expect that equality holds. However, `h.equals(h*)` returns `false`. Note: of course, `h != h*` holds.

This is due the fact that Hibernates uses an instance of `PersistentBag` instead of `ArrayList` to represent `h*`'s states.

At a first glance it is hard to find another business key for `History`. Two histories are equal if they have the same course of events, aren't they? Furthermore, why should I have to adopt my model to the persistence layer while its logic seems sound (I may err, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to include a List in a equals/hashCode comparison for a root entity? This is a wrong approach.

Equality should be based on the underlying table record unicity constraint. Ideally, [you should have a natural key in every database table](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-equals-and-hashcode/) like a SSN, email address, domain name, [UUID](https://vladmihalcea.com//hibernate-and-uuid-identifiers/).

Sometimes, you don't have a natural id, but then you still have the primary key. Contrary to popular belief, [you can use the PK for equals/hashCode](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-equals-and-hashcode/), you just have to make sure that hashCode renders a constant value for every entity state transition.

If you worry about hashCode performance, then you should know that a persistent collection is not meant to store large amounts of data. So, prior to having the hashCode as a real bottleneck (as depicted in Effective Java), you'd have to fetch the collection, and the fetching tons of data is way more costly anyway. If that's the case, you are better off using a query instead.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing you did not (correctly) implement the equals method of State? If you did, are the states in the List in the same order?

But, you should not use referenced entities to define your equals/hashCode especially if, like in your case, they are lazy loaded. If you load your history without the states and then for any of numerous reasons the equals gets hibernate will perform 2 queries for this.
Furthermore, if you detach History and then call equals on it you will get a LazyIntializationException.

Try to find another business key for your History that does not depend and other entities.

Comment: I am sure that I implemented all the `equals` methods correctly - all model classes are tested by `equalsverifier`. The states are in the same order. In my test case, I basically create a history H, persist it, and finally I do a search - in a new session - which returns H, name it H* as it was returned by Hibernate. I would expect that `H.equals(H*)` holds, although `H == H*` does not hold, of course.

Comment: BTW, `State.equals()` is not called at all precisely because `PersistentBag.equals()` delegates to `Object.equals()` instead of checking the elements in the list.

Comment: Indeed, I did not know what your Objects was but I assume now you use guava. You either need to loop through the lists yourself or have a look at com.google.common.collect.Iterators.elementsEqual.

Comment: The relevant discussion on [Hibernate forum](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=971056).